# Asp.net Mvc centralised app settings?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, appsettings

What is the scenario for changing app settings on an Mvc App if one is using a load balancer with say 4 boxes? (e.g on ec2).

Does one have to manually change the appSetting in each box (to change a particular config)_

Is there any way to centralise this sort of this?

Is a database recommend over appSettings?

Comment: Typically you'd have some sort of replication set up to copy config files between load balanced servers?

Comment: You should look at automated deployment to do this for you

Comment: Do you mean a packager like udeploy?